# How to set max character length in angular mat text area?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How can we check the total characters while user is typing in angular text area?

While user input his data the text area will check the total character input and will show error if morethan 1000 characters and show now allow user to add more characters if exceeds.

#code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlex hintLabel="Max 1000 characters">
                  <mat-label>Reason</mat-label>
                  <textarea (keypress)="textAreaKeyPress($event)"
                    formControlName="text"
                    [maxLength]="150" 
                    matInput
                    required
                    cdkTextareaAutosize
                    cdkAutosizeMinRows="3"
                    cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"
                  ></textarea>
              <mat-error *ngIf="">Max 1000 characters</mat-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add template reference variable.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlex hintLabel="Max 1000 characters">
              <mat-label>Reason</mat-label>
              <textarea (keypress)="textAreaKeyPress($event)"
                formControlName="text"
                maxlength="1000" 
                matInput
                required
                cdkTextareaAutosize
                cdkAutosizeMinRows="3"
                cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"
                #description></textarea>
          <mat-error *ngIf="description.value?.length > 1000">Max 1000 characters</mat-error>
```

Comment: @S Rana , I did try your solution but it does not work Sir,

Comment: it should show mat error and should not allow users to input more characters

Comment: the remaining issue sir is that it does not show the mat error

Comment: A mat-error inside a mat-form-field only it's showed by defect when the control is invalid and touched (you blur). You can change this using a ErrorSatetMatcher as show in the doc: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

Comment: @Eliseo can you post your answer

Comment: just done, but really I think that the problem is that you use `maxLength` and is `maxlength` (is in lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

Complementary my comment. It's only copy the example, but we can "play" with ErrorMatcher. Imagine we want that show the error instantanly if length>10 but not if is null (being to write and remove the text). We can change our Class

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (
    //is dirty and the error is maxlength
    (control.dirty && control.errors && control.errors.maxlength) || 
     //or is touched or submited
     control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}
```

Or we want to show the error but the control was valid

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher2 implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && 
          ((control.value && control.value.length>10) ||
          (control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted)))
    );
  }
}

//here our controls has only Validators.required
```

Finally we can use mat-hit to show an advertisment

```
   <mat-hint *ngIf="control3.value.length>10">
      Max length 100
    </mat-hint>
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsx2tq?file=src/app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html)

NOTE: To avoid maxLength alwway can use

```
<input maxlength="10"> //see is lowercase and not enclosed by []
```